# How to retry a request inside my viewmodel

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I'm trying to retry the logic of getting data from Firebase, what my app does is the follow.

If there is no internet connection it will trigger the Failure Resource and will show a retry button, but when I click this button, it seems that the viewmodel does not request again the data, instead is just showin my progress without requesting again the data to my repo

### UI

```
 viewModel.getPrizes.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { it ->
            when(it){
                is Resource.Loading -> {
                  // Loading...
                }
                is Resource.Success -> {
                    hideProgress()
                    setArrayData(it.data)
                }
                is Resource.Failure -> {
                    hideProgress()
                    hidePrizes()
                    retry_constrain.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    btn_retry.setOnClickListener{
                        viewModel.getPrizes
                        showProgress()
                        retry_constrain.visibility = View.GONE
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(
                        requireContext(),
                        "An error has ocourred:${it.throwable.message}",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()
                }
            }
        })
```

What I spect here is in my Resource.Failure to request again the data after pressing my `btn_retry` but instead, it only shows my progress bar and nothing happens

### ViewModel

```
class PrizesViewModel(private val useCase:IPrizes): ViewModel() {

    val getPrizes = liveData(Dispatchers.IO) {
        emit(Resource.Loading())
        try{
            val prizes = useCase.fetchPrizes()
            emit(prizes)
        }catch (e:Exception){
            Crashlytics.logException(e.cause)
            emit(Resource.Failure(e.cause!!))
        }
    }
}
```

Why is not re-fetching my values after calling again `viewModel.getPrizes` in my `Resource.Failure` ?

Comment: I'm removing the Firebase tag, as the issue and related code here doesn't seem to have anything to do with it directly.

Answer (score 2):

The `LiveData` from the second call to `viewModel.getPrizes` has no `Observers` attached to it, and hence it will not get a value until there is one.

You would have to call `viewModel.getPrizes.observe(...)` again inside the current `Observer` which is not optimal.

You will have to rethink your design a bit so you can trigger a new call to `useCase.fetchPrizes()` and still get the new value by observing the original `LiveData`.

Comment: is there a way to recall this function whitin this coroutine scope ? because since I'm using suspend funcitons I will need to move my whole code

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was a Transformation, since a Transformation can be triggered whenever the mutable value changes, I can retry the whole coroutine doing so

```
 private val shouldRetry = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
    val fetchPrizes: LiveData<Resource<Prizes>> = Transformations.switchMap(shouldRetry) {
        liveData(context = viewModelScope.coroutineContext + Dispatchers.IO) {
          emit(Resource.Loading())
        try{
            val prizes = useCase.fetchPrizes()
            emit(prizes)
        }catch (e:Exception){
            Crashlytics.logException(e.cause)
            emit(Resource.Failure(e.cause!!))
        }
        }
    }

    fun retryData(retry: Boolean) {
        shouldRetry.value = retry
    }
```

Then from my UI I just call `viewModel.retryData(true)` whenever I want